# Flickering when editing style element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Basically when I edit the inner HTML of the style element, my whole DOM flickers. Is there anyway I can resolve this? Or better yet, is there any way for me to edit my input range track color without the need of directly editing the style element.

Here is what I mean by flickering: https://i.imgur.com/C67Ge0H.gifv

```
function backgroundChange(src) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function () {
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();
    var rgb = colorThief.getColor(img);
    document.getElementById("background").style.cssText += `background-image: url(${this.src})`;
    return changeHoverColor(rgb);
  };
  img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  img.src = 'http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + src; // Bypass CORS restriction to avoid tainted canvas.
}

function changeHoverColor(...rgb) {
  return document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].innerHTML = `
    input[type=range]#time:hover::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
      background: rgb(${rgb});
    }
  `;
}
```

Comment: Off topic: I would say you'd be better off by just using a div or span instead of a slider or like [`this`](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/#article-header-id-3). On topic: it seems the flickering occurs because the image is changed in javascript. I don't think the whole DOM is flickering

Comment: It's actually not the background image changing causing the page to flicker after testing. Its the changeHoverColor function that changes the style element that causes it to flicker. Though my slider is exactly what you provided me in the link, but I'm trying to create like dynamic colors on my slider depending on the dominant color of the background image.